# Repository pattern with multiple databases of different types

Tags: c#, database, asp.net-core, repository-pattern

I've developed a generic repository pattern with EF Core (`GenericRepository.cs`), but  want to extend this by adding it to multiple databases.

`GenericRepository.cs`

```
public class GenericRepository<TEntity, TContext> : IGenericRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class where TContext : DbContext
{
            
    private readonly TContext _context;
    
    public GenericRepository(TContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }
    
    public TEntity GetById(string id)
    {
        return _context.Set<TEntity>().Find(id);
    }

    ...
}
```

With that in mind I then made the `ContextRepository.cs` generic by adding a `TContext` to the class. This only worked if the context class was of type `DbContext`.

`ContextRepository.cs`

```
public class ContextRepository<TContext> : IContextRepository where TContext : DbContext
{
    private readonly TContext _dbContext;
    private readonly Dictionary<Type, object> _repositories = new Dictionary<Type, object>();
    public Dictionary<Type, object> Repositories
    {
        get { return _repositories; }
        set { Repositories = value; }
    }

    public ContextRepository(TContext dbContext)
    {
        _dbContext = dbContext;
    }

    public IGenericRepository<TEntity> Repository<TEntity>() where TEntity : class
    {
        if (Repositories.Keys.Contains(typeof(TEntity)))
        {
            return Repositories[typeof(TEntity)] as IGenericRepository<TEntity>;
        }

        IGenericRepository<TEntity> repo = new GenericRepository<TEntity, TContext>(_dbContext);
        Repositories.Add(typeof(TEntity), repo);
        return repo;
    }
}
```

Here's the issue:

I have two different database contexts (`ApiAuthorizationDbContext` and `DbContext`).

Is there a way/workaround to achieve this with both contexts in the same generic context class?

Comment: If ApiAuthorizationDbContext is derived from DbContext then it will also work in the generic repository, new ContextRepository<ApiAuthorizationDbContext>();

Comment: You may not be aware but you're not supposed to implement the repository pattern with EF because EF already does it. The `DbContext` is a unit of work and each `DbSet` is a repository.

Comment: @MarcusHöglund thank you for the suggestion. Will give it a go and test.

Comment: @John Thank you, I did not think about it like that.

Comment: I learned the hard way. We used the same pattern with ADO.NET in my office and we started using EF fairly early on and started by implementing our own repositories too, but it created a number of issues.

Comment: @John I can just imagine the frustrating issues this can cause. I quickly read up about this. You saved me tons of hours!

Answer (score 1):

As *@John* stated in the comments.

> You may not be aware but you're not supposed to implement the repository pattern with EF because EF already does it. The DbContext is a unit of work and each DbSet is a repository.

In my particular case this was unnecessary. I found this article explaining it in more detail for anyone wandering down the same path.

[Repository Pattern with Entity Framework Core is obsolete](https://dotnetstories.wordpress.com/2021/10/17/repository-pattern-with-entity-framework-core-is-obsolete/#:%7E:text=Developers%20building%20applications%20with%20ASP,unit%20testing%20and%20mock%20contexts.)

> Developers building applications with ASP.Net Core and Entity Framework Core should not use UoW and Repository pattern anymore. EF Core supports unit testing and mock contexts.